# git ignore to folder end with the same string

Tags: git, gitignore

I am using git 1.9.5 and have some folders which are end with the same string.

e.g.

```
a.Rcheck
b.Rcheck
c.Rcheck
```

I have tried .*Rcheck, but seems not work for me.

How could I use git rules to ignore it?

Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: How about `*.Rcheck` ?

Comment: Are you trying to ignore **folders** or **files**?

Comment: for folders. *.Rcheck is working for folder too. My thought is only working for files.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add:

`*.Rcheck/`

to a `gitignore` file which sits above the directories you want to ignore.

If you want to also ignore files ending in `.Rcheck` then add:

`*.Rcheck`